# How do I go up a level in a doc root?

Tags: php

I have a folder admin that has config.php, admin.php.

I want to get navmenu.php in the includes folder.

How do I go up a level from admin.php then to navmenu.php?

```
admin
  config.php, admin.php

includes
  navmenu.php
```

easy question but I forgot what the name is so i can't seem to google it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
include ("../navmenu.php");
```

`../` means one level back, `../../` means two levels back, `../../../` means three levels back and so on.

Answer (score 1):

`..` changes the directory to upper directory.